# Cannot install Carla on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, vst

This might appear as a really stupid question, but I can't figure it out myself.

I cannot install [Carla](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Carla) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64 bit). They offer 3 ways to install Carla, and none is working yet for me.

1. Pressing **Debian/Ubuntu** on their downloadpage reports:

   > could not find carla-git.

   BTW: [kxstudio repo](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories) is installed.
2. Precompiled binary reports an error after `chmod +x Carla && chmod +x CarlaConfig` :

   ```
   $ ./Carla
   Carla: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data:
     Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
   Aborted (core dumped)
   ```
3. Building from source is installable. But when I try to open it, nothing appears.

I should maybe stick to one solution, but I'm really confused right now which path to take.

**Edit 2**:
I just did a new clean installation of the kxstudio repo. Here is my output of (extracted the relevant part)

```
sudo apt update


Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/ubuntus/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

then trying to install carla:

```
sudo apt install carla-git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package carla-git
```

Answer (score 3):

Try first:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then

```
sudo apt install carla-git
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: this is the answer - totally works after installing KXStudio repo

Comment: `sudo apt install carla-git` throws:  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package carla-git`

I ran all the instructions to install the kxstudio repos. Here is a screenshot of my Software & Updates https://imgur.com/a/sZDR3CE .
So the problem seems kxstudio repo not be installed properly?

Comment: @Sirhennihau Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @Sirhennihau did you run both sets of commands? It works fine for me on 17.10 (also, your screenshot is too small to read)

Comment: Yeah, I ran both sets of commands. It was working for me too, when I was on Ubuntu 17.10 .

Comment: oh right @Sirhennihau yeah the repo presumably has no package for 18.04 yet

Comment: @Zanna I apologize if my comment offended anyone but,  I made my comment after the OP edited Q and stated they already tried this answer, which did not work. To me this answer is incomplete and not a answer or help to the OP.

Comment: @stumblebee I'm sure nobody was offended and you're quite right that this isn't the answer for 18.04 and so not really an answer for this question. You might have explained in your comment, but it's my bad

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully installed Carla on Ubuntu 18.04.  Here's how to do it:

1. go to http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories and install the kxstudio-repos.deb package.  You need KXStudio repository for Carla.
2. NOW you can go to http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Carla and click on the  Debian/Ubuntu (via KXStudio repositories) link to install Carla.

If you are trying to get Windows VST files to work in Ubuntu, I found this video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiaWozQ69eE

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues with the kxstudio repository in the past, especially with the bundled version of Carla. Therefore I now download the latest version of the actual release files from their Github repository here:

https://github.com/falkTX/Carla/releases

I find that the latest release at the time I am writing this (Carla_2.0-RC2-linux64.tar.xz) is working very well on both standard Ubuntu 18.04, as well as Ubuntu Studio 18.04. Furthermore, I use it successfully to load Windows-based VST files with the standard version of Wine that comes with 18.04 (wine-3.0).

To prove my version of Ubuntu:

```
 $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

And here is the output of "./Carla" if I start it on the commandline:

```
$ ./Carla
Carla self-contained executable 1.9.11 (2.0-RC1), based on UnZipSFX.
Launching: '/tmp/carla/carla'
LRDF Support disabled for static build (LADSPA-RDF will be disabled)
Carla 1.9.12 (2.0-RC2) started, status:
  Python version: 3.2.3
  Qt version:     4.8.7
  PyQt version:   4.9.1
  Binary dir:     /tmp/carla
  Resources dir:  /tmp/carla/resources
libjack.so.0 loaded sucessfully!
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.12
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2017 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:PCH|hw:PCH|512|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 512 frames (11.6 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
```

I hope that this helps!